# na.rm for other values in R

Tags: r, na.rm

I have a data frame

```
df=data.frame(a=1:5,b=c(1,3,4,-999999,4))
```

and want to calculate the average of it, but want to exlcude the outlier, -9999 in this case

Is there a command similar to

```
na.rm
```

so I can go

```
apply(df,1,function(x) mean(if x>-100 & x <100))
```

note that my df if 600 x 50 dim

Comment: `mean` has a trim argument that will remove some percentage of the extreme observations. This may be helpful.

Comment: that is a nice idea, but it only removes values from the end:      observations to be trimmed from each end of x before the mean is computed, and my df has many outliers in many possible positions

Comment: When the help file says "each end of x," it means each end of `sort(x)`. So, for example: `df=data.frame(a=1:5,b=c(1,3,4,-999999,4), c=16:20); apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x, trim=.7))` will trim the max and min and return the median.

Comment: Are you looking for the mean of the whole data frame or row- or column-wise means? If the whole data frame, you can just do `mean(df[df > -100 & df < 100])`, which returns 3.

Comment: @alex I posted a solution below.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @ ulfelder I will eventually seek the mean of the whole df, but need to exclude all outliers, so planned to take the mean of the apply fcn

Comment: Your code and your expected output is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the mean of the whole data frame, you can cut to the chase and use:

```
mean(df[df > -100 & df < 100])
```

When I apply that to the df you gave, I get the expected answer: 3.

Answer (score 2):

We can `replace` the values in 'df' based on the logical condition to NA and use `rowMeans`.

```
rowMeans(replace(df, !(df < 100 & df > -100) , NA), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 1.0 2.5 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

Or as @RHertel mentioned in the comments

```
rowMeans(replace(df, abs(df) > 100 , NA), na.rm=TRUE) 
#[1] 1.0 2.5 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

---

Or another option would be to loop through the columns of 'df', get the outlier observations with `boxplot.stats`, convert the outliers to `NA` and do the `rowMeans`.

```
rowMeans(sapply(df, function(x)  x*NA^(x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out)), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 1.0 2.5 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

Comment: I like the `boxplot.stats()` option. Good way to detect outliers; much better than a manual threshold.

Comment: > rowMeans(replace(df, df < 100 & df > -100, NA), na.rm=TRUE)
[1]     NaN     NaN     NaN -999999     NaN
Not what I am looking for

Comment: @alex Based on the example showed, it works for me.  In your original data, there may not be any observation in a row that meets that the condition, so NaN.  For that you cannot blame the solution.

Comment: odd indeed, it did not work right now with the df given

Comment: @alex Sorry, the condition should been negated in the first one.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You write your own function excluding -9999 value for your case

```
y<-function(x){mean(x[!grepl("\\-999",x)])}

y(df$b)

[1] 3
```